# Updating where id in stored procedure - enormous amount of fetches

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

```
UPDATE TABLE SET SOMETHING = 1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM STORED_PROCEDURE)
```

Records in TABLE = 2100

Records from stored procedure = 50

This statement cousing enormous amount of fetches (31M!) on firebird 2.5 server. Why? Shouldn't it first select id's from stored procedure and then put it in where clause? What should I do to make it work?

Comment: @JustMe: Is STORED_PROCEDURE a table or a function, and if the latter what's the procedure doing in terms of database access?

Comment: @Bob It's a selectable stored procedure - one "for select" with suspend

Comment: @JustMe: OK - and what does the stored procedure do in terms of database access?

Comment: @Bob It is selecting rows from database (select from table) - operating on the same table as UPDATE

Comment: @Bob Just try to do SELECT ... WHERE ID IN (STORED_PROCEDURE) - You'll see the problem. It fetches stored procedure for all record in select table and then cut it in where clause

Comment: @JustMe: Could you edit your post to include the code in the stored procedure?

Comment: I understand the stored procedure applies some filters on the table so as to limit the output, so you are using those filters indirectly, using the condition `WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM STORED_PROCEDURE)`. But would it make any difference in performance if you omitted the stored procedure and applied the filters directly?

Comment: @Andiry The Stored Procedure was made for getting the filter so I can't omit it. The problem is that stored procedure is called for every record in UPDATE table. Refering to this article: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq143/ good ideai is to left join but I can't in UPDATE clause :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
declare variable myid integer;    
begin
    for
        select id from stored_procedure into :myID
    do begin
      update table set something = 1 where table.id = :myID;
    end
end
```